# How to extract Math Equation from a string in python?

Tags: python, math, equation

I have a problem with math equation and string. If a user gives a math equation in string format how do I get that out of string and calculate values?

```
Input: 
x = 1
y = 2
formula = "x+y"
Output:
formula = x+y
formula = 3
```

Comment: Have you written any code to try to do this? What's the issue with this code?

Comment: You can print the formula using a simple print(formula) -> it will show up without quotes. To get the result, you could run eval(formula), although that has possible safety problems if your user gives unsafe input.

Comment: @anvoice is there any other way than eval? as eval is unsafe and also when () are given to formula it gives a wrong answer

Comment: You could give f strings a try. For example, `f'{10 + (2 * 5)}'` gives '20'.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> x, y = 1, 2
>>> formula = "x+y"
>>> print('formula = ' + formula)
formula = x+y
>>> print('formula = ' + str(eval(formula)))
formula = 3
```

Comment: is there any other way with out eval?

Comment: I didn't find so far